# iPhone UITextField Apostrophe issue 

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uitextfield

There is a problem with posts in my UITextfield.  Any time a word that has an apostrophe in it, it adds a backslash.

So my test post says in NSLog "I\'m thinking there may be a problem with words that end in \'s"

It should read: "I'm thinking there may be a problem with words that end in 's".

Comment: Add some code? Some more information about where you're storing/displaying text so that it's showing that backslash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like escaping -- somewhere along the line, your data is being escaped.  The problem isn't in the UITextField, it's in some other part of your code.  Check what string is being sent to the field, you'll find that it's escaped there.  Track your code back from there.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Post;

Comment: I am simply taking the input in textfield and then assigning it to string..Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you post some more code? There may be something that is causing this that you are unaware of. Just add it to your post. It would be easier to answer your question that way.

Comment: I got it, its actually php issue, when  I am posting it through web service and after retrieving it . The backslash occurs

Comment: Sounds like your server may have magic quotes on.  You should be able to disable those through HTACCESS -- or better yet, complain to the server admin that they shouldn't be on!  (Edit:  Also, it's considered good manners to mark an answer as 'accepted' if it's correct)